# I accidentally lost my queen and I resign is that a bad thing to do?

Tags: strategy, online-chess, queens

If it's bad what should I do? And I why resigning after I lost my queen is bad?
I have no way to win, and I and I have to resign because I am going to lose anyway.
So is it bad?

```
[Event "tetrahedronx7 vs. MikeKettering"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2023-02-24"]
[White "tetrahedronx7"]
[Black "MikeKettering"]
[Result "0-1"]
[WhiteElo "693"]
[BlackElo "825"]
[TimeControl "standard"]
[Termination "MikeKettering won by resignation"]
[FEN ""]
1. e4 e5 2. d4 exd4 3. Qxd4 Nc6 4. Qxg7 Bxg7 5. Be3 a6 6. Nd2 Bxb2 7. Rd1 Bc3 8.
Be2 Bxd2+ 9. Bxd2 f6 10. Nf3 h5 11. O-O Nh6 12. Nh4 Nf7 13. Ng6 Rg8 14. Nf4 d6
15. Nxh5 Bh3 16. Bf3 Bg4 17. Bxg4 Rxg4 18. Rde1 Nfe5 19. Bc3 Rh4 20. Ng7+ Kf7
21. Nf5 Rh7 22. Nd4 Ne7 23. Nf5 N7c6 24. Ng3 Nc4 25. Nf5 Qg8 0-1
```

Comment: The decision is of course yours , when you resign or if you resign at all or play until mate. But it is a good attitude to resign absolutely hopeless positions. In fact, this was the case already after the huge blunder Qg7 here, and after Bg7 , White could well have resigned. But of course you can play some more moves and hope for a big blunder from the opponent.

Comment: In short, it is never bad to resgin, in contrary. But do not resign in draw or even won positions ! This happens more often than one would expect.

Answer (score 6):

No. Resigning is a perfectly acceptable way to end a game of chess. In fact the vast majority of decisive games finish this way. You should not feel there is any stigma whatsoever associated with resigning in a lost position such as the one above.

Answer (score 2):

Not resigning after losing your Queen is insulting to your opponent. Your are doubting their ability to finish off what should be a very simple task. But if both players are beginners, maybe that doubt is justified.

The best criterion is to ask yourself, "How will my opponent feel if I play on?" and if you think they will justifiably feel bored and insulted, then you should resign.